# How to write a conditional statement in vsts if previous task fails in a task group

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We would like to send slack messages only if the previous task fails. How can we specify the previous task using task groups?

It is getting skipped!!!

[image]

Tried this but could not locate anything with the previous task.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t the task condition feature for the tasks in task group, also the task group doesn’t have the condition feature.

There is a related user voice: [VSTS Task Group usage should have a conditional usage](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20591299-vsts-task-group-usage-should-have-a-conditional-us) (You can submit a new user voice)

The workaround is that you can put the tasks out of the task group, which need to be run according to the condition statement.

On the other hand, there is Only when a previous task has failed condition:

[image]